# Is there a way to test an int against a string? (Java)

Tags: java

I'm trying to write an if/else to test user input for integers. If they input an int, the program proceeds. If they enter anything else, the program produces an error message asking for correct input. Is this anywhere in the ball park?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] foo;
        foo = new int[3];

        foo[0]=1;
        foo[1]=2;
        foo[2]=3;

        System.out.print("Make a choice between 0 and 2: ");
        int itemChoice = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (itemChoice != foo) {  
           System.out.print("Not a valid choice");  
        }  
        else {  
           System.out.print("Valid choice. You picked " + itemChoice);
        }  
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
 required: int
 found:    boolean
 test.java:17: error: incomparable types: int and int[]
        if (itemChoice != foo) {
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What about [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))?

Comment: @thegrinner What I have so far doesn't work. My complier says there's something wrong with my use of is not equal to.

Comment: @TyGivens: In the future, copy/paste the (compiler's) error message(s) into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're comparing a `int[]` (int array) with an `int`:

```
itemChoice != foo
```

Should be:

```
boolean tmp = false;
for (int i=0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    if (foo[i] == itemChoice) {
       tmp = true;
    }
}
if (tmp) {
    System.out.print("Valid choice. You picked " + itemChoice);
}  
else {  
    System.out.print("Not a valid choice");  
}
```

Comment: This works, about half way. Is there a way to add a test so that if the user enters something other than an int that it displays the else message

Comment: If you want to read whatever the user enter, you should use `keyboard.nextLine();`, you'll get a String. To test if it's an int, just do a try/catch on `Integer.parseInt(itemChoice)`. It will throw a `NumberFormatException` if itemChoice isn't an int, so in the catch section, call `System.out.print("Not a valid choice");`

Comment: I haven't learned try/catches yet. I'm still on a beginners level. I'll look that up and see if I can figure it out

Answer (score 6):

Try below method to validate your input:

[`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29)

```
int itemChoice =0;
while(true){
    if(keyboard.hasNextInt()){    
        itemChoice = keyboard.nextInt();    
        // Do something.
        break;
    }
    else{    
        System.out.print("Not a valid choice Try again");
        continue;

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean like this: itemChoice = Scanner.hasNextInt();

Comment: @Achintaya Jha It works, but when it gets to the else, it goes into an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put your code inside a loop, like `while` ?

So then:

```
while (my input is not a number) {
 //Here I do the block of code.
 //I can implement an if to handle the error messages
}
```

I haven't use Scanner class too much or have any similar requirement, but maybe it can help. Best regards.

Comment: A while  loop seems like a good idea, but I don't really know what test to use.

Comment: mmm... what do you mean by you don't really know what test to use? you need help to apply this while loop to your code or you're not sure about which answer use for your test? we're here to give you a hand.

Comment: I just solved this with a try/catch. Thank you for you input though. Next time I will try to be clearer. I'm still somewhat of a beginner so even simple things are a little difficult for me.

Comment: don't worry partner, we're here to help, congrats for solving your problem, keep on, simple things could be difficult sometimes not only for beginners, keep on, just practice and dedication. Best regards.